# Local Binary Pattern in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to execute local binary pattern in MATLAB using the image processing toolbox. When i execute I can't get a LBP image and LBP histogram.

```
   clear all;
    close all;
    clc;
    I=imread('test.png');
    figure,imshow(I)
    %% Crop
    I2 = imcrop(I);
    figure, imshow(I2)
    w=size(I2,1);
    h=size(I2,2);
    %% LBP
    scale = 2.^[7 6 5; 0 -inf 4; 1 2 3]; 
    for i=2:w-1
        for j=2:h-1
            J0=I2(i,j);
            I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>J0;
            I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>J0;
            I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>J0; 
            I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>J0;
            I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>J0; 
            I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>J0; 
            I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>J0; 
            I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>J0;
            LBP(i,j)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0;

        end
    end
    figure,imshow(LBP)
    figure,imhist(LBP)
```

what is the issue.i am supposed to get numbers from 0 to 255.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>J0;` creates a logical as output. If you don't go and cast this to something else, you're image will only be zeros and ones.

The easiest way is to initialize `I3` outside the loop, i.e. have `I3=I2;` before you start looping. This way, all your assignments inside the loop get converted to whatever class `I2` was.

Answer (score 0):

use :
figure,imshow(uint8(LBP));

Its becuase LBP image is in DOUBLE, you need to cast it.