# How to implement Uniform LBP?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local Binary Pattern in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406314/local-binary-pattern-in-matlab)

I would like to implement uniform LBP. This is the definiton given by wikipedia for uniform LBP.

> A local binary pattern is called uniform if the binary pattern
>   contains at most two bitwise transitions from 0 to 1 or vice versa
>   when the bit pattern is traversed circularly. For example, the
>   patterns 00000000 (0 transitions), 01110000 (2 transitions) and
>   11001111 (2 transitions) are uniform whereas the patterns 11001001 (4
>   transitions) and 01010010 (6 transitions) are not. In the computation
>   of the LBP labels, uniform patterns are used so that there is a
>   separate label for each uniform pattern and all the non-uniform
>   patterns are labeled with a single label. For example, when using
>   (8,R) neighborhood, there are a total of 256 patterns, 58 of which are
>   uniform, which yields in 59 different labels.

I have written code for LBP but not sure how to convert it to a uniform LBP. Below is the code for LBP.

```
for i=2:m-1
    for j=2:n-1
        J0=I2(i,j);
        I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>J0;
        I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>J0;
        I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>J0; 
        I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>J0;
        I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>J0; 
        I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>J0; 
        I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>J0; 
        I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>J0;
        LBP(i,j)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0;

    end
end
figure,imshow(uint8(LBP))
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using MATLAB.

Comment: Are you more interested in understanding the concept of Uniform LBP, or do you already understand it, but just don't know how to modify the code?

Comment: Understand the concept but not sre how to modify the code..

Comment: In that case, this question is still a better fit for StackOverflow. I'm going to migrate this one over there so you don't have to delete/re-post this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps

1. Your next step is to construct a lookup table for the values that are stored into `LBP`.

   - The lookup table maps the 256 possible combinations into 59 different labels.
   - If speed is not important, the table can be built with a for-loop.
2. Map `LBP` into the 59 labels using the table.

   - `labeled = table(LBP) % this is called table lookup or MATLAB indexing.`
3. Perform any additional work with those 59 labels.

---

Suggestions (although not necessary for implementation)

1. There is no need to use a 2D matrix for I3. The eight neighbors of the current pixel are local to the current pixel you are processing; therefore you can simply assign them to `I3(1), I3(2), ... I3(8)` because they will be reassigned each time you move on to the next center pixel `(i,j)`.

---

```
function table = BitwiseToLBP
    % we reserve label 0 for non-uniform
    table = zeros(1, 256);
    nextLabel = 1;
    for k = 1:256,
        bits = bitand(k, 2.^(0:7)) > 0;
        if IsUniformLBP(bits),
            table(k) = nextLabel;
            nextLabel = nextLabel + 1;
        else
            table(k) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
function IsUniformLBP(bits)
    nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) == 2;
end
```

Comment: just like to ask you a question.. bits = bitand(k, 2.^(0:7)) > 0;
what does this line do?

Comment: An anomymous user proposed an edit which should have been a comment (but is too long to fit in a single comment): " 
I'm not so sure, but I think there might be a mistake in the code, I tried and I only get 56 different values, where non of them is repeatable, I believe there should be 58 different values, (its 59 including one bin for all non-uniform patterns)." ...

Comment: ... "in-addition, the entire idea of uniform patterns is to give "same" rotational lbp codes the same uplpb code, for example if 7 and 194 are rotationaly uniform then both of them should get the same uplbp code. I tried this code here, and it's not what happens... Will appreciate any improvement."

Comment: @KeithThompson: sorry I am not familiar with LBP. I only coded my answer based on the description in the original question. Please go ahead and implement the changes into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @rwong: If you've heard of LBP, you know more about it than I do. I saw the quoted wording in a suggested edit from an anonymous user (who probably wouldn't be able to post comments). I decided that it should be a comment instead, so I posted it as one and voted to reject the edit. If you think editing it into your answer would improve it, by all means do so.

Comment: This code works perfect, but it needs a small bug fix. According to paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/showciting?cid=4608087, uniform patterns have at most 2 bit transitions. Therefore, nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) == 2; should be nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) <= 2;

Comment: Its been a long time, but there are actually 2 issues. Firstly, as @oki mentioned, nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) == 2; should be nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) <= 2. Moreover, k should run from 0 to 255. And since MATLAB does not index from 0, you would have to index into (k+1) for the table

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

```
 sum = abs(I3(k-1,l-1)-I3(k-1,l))+ abs(I3(k-1,l)-I3(k-1,l+1))+ abs(I3(k-1,l+1)-I3(k,l+1))+ abs(I3(k,l+1)-I3(k+1,l+1))+abs(I3(k+1,l+1)-I3(k+1,l))+abs(I3(k+1,l)-I3(k+1,l-1))+abs(I3(k+1,l-1)-I3(k,l-1));
    if(sum <=2)
            UniformHist = [UniformHist Hist];
    end
```